# how to read pdf by blocks rather by lines in R using "pdftools"?

Tags: r, pdftools

With {pdftools} package, we can read pdf into R environment. But it reads by lines rather by blocks. So, when there are multiple columns, the result becomes a mess.

For example, we like to have it in this way.
[image]

but it comes in this way
[image]

Have tried to read it into data.table, and split it into 2 columns. But the attempt failed, since the code can't tell if the single space is for the words or the columns.

Please advise.

Comment: I'd found a post about this issue.
Please find it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229791/scraping-two-column-pdf

Comment: the concept was easy that it uses long spaces as the separator. it's rigid however it seemed the only option we have for now.